# Will Angular Scope events (sent via `$broadcast`) go on the event queue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to `$broadcast` an event to indicate some AJAX is happening, so the UI disables controls in a form. Currently it seems these events do not go onto the event queue and are immediately handled.

The code I am working on depends on this behaviour, so I am wondering how dependable is this? Some authoritative link would be helpful (the doc does not mention anything specific).

Comment: Instead of using events I would set some scope variable like `isLoading` to `true` when you send your request and set it back to `false` when the request's promise resolves. You can put the variable on `$rootScope` if you need to access it everywhere in your app.

Comment: @muenchdo A `loading` flag was actually the original design; however, code has evolved and there are multiple services doing AJAX and multiple UIs displayed concurrently, so there has to be multiple flags. Also, as the controllers (in additon to the views) needs to be notified of the events, a call to some `$scope` function is inevitable and I think event handlers better represent the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - After reading your comments, it might make more sense for you to build a queue system with dependency injection and callbacks.

```
app.factory('FirstService', function($rootScope, SecondService){
  $rootScope.loading = true
  .success(function(){
    SecondService.AJAXCall();
  });
})
.factory('SecondService', function($rootScope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.AJAXCALL = function(){
    $rootScope.processing = true;
    //AJAX Call
    .complete(function(){
      $rootScope.processing = false;
      $rootScope.loading = false;
    })
  }
})
.controller('FirstController', function($rootScope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.loading = $rootScope.loading;
})
.controller('SecondController', function($rootScope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.processing = $rootScope.processing;
});

<div ng-controller="FirstController as first">
   <form ng-disabled="first.loading"><form>
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondController as second">
   <img ng-show="second.processing" />
</div>
```

`$broadcast` [blasts the event down scope](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html), so it makes sense that they would be fired immediately and not put into an event queue. Here's a visualization:
[image]

Like what muenchdo suggest, you might want to add a scope variable to indicate whether controls should be enabled/disabled.

Add the logic to the controller:

```
app.module('AppCtrl', function($rootScope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.loading = $rootScope.loading;
});
```

Then add the ngDisabled logic to the html:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
   <form ng-disabled="app.loading"><form>
</div>
```

Then before your AJAX call, set the `$rootScope` variable:

```
app.service($rootScope){
  $rootScope.loading = true;
  //AJAX CALL
  .complete(function(){
    $rootScope.loading = false;
  });
}
```